# SolidColorBrushes as Dynamic Resources are not updating

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net

I have a window with a number or Dynamic Resources for colors/brushes on it.

For example this; EXAMPLE 1 **DOES NOT UPDATE** "DynamicResource ColFancyMed"

```
<Rectangle x:Name="dbBarPeekOutRect1" Margin="3,10,10,10" >
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ColFancyMed}" />
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

When my App starts the Resource file is read and the right color is shown.

These colors are however themed and so I have a number of resource dictionaries with these resource keys in them. Thus I change the resource dictionary like this

```
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.RemoveAt(0)
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Insert(0, dict)
```

This works elsewhere but not on the above.  The funny thing is if I use the following.  The only difference I can see is one is a Color and the other is a SolidColorBrush.

EXAMPLE 2 **DOES UPDATE** "DynamicResource ColFancyMed"

```
<Rectangle x:Name="dbBarPeekOutRect1" Margin="3,10,10,10" Fill="{DynamicResource ColFancyMed}"/>
```

Then the color changes.

**So why does example 1 NOT work and example 2 work?**

Similarly another place where it does not work is in the  for example;

```
<Storyboard x:Key="dbBarPeekOutHighlight">
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="dbBarPeekOutRect1">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{DynamicResource ColFancyMed}"/>
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="#FFF2F6F9"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="dbBarPeekOutRect2">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{DynamicResource ColFancyMed}"/>
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="#FFF2F6F9"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Specifically what you need? Some do not understand the question.

Comment: If I swap resource files then some dynamic resources do not update. Some do.  Why does the above not update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the last example with the storyboard, as MSDN states [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742868.aspx)

> You can't use dynamic resource references or data binding expressions to set Storyboard or animation property values. That's because everything inside a Style must be thread-safe, and the timing system must Freeze Storyboard objects to make them thread-safe. A Storyboard cannot be frozen if it or its child timelines contain dynamic resource references or data binding expressions. For more information about freezing and other Freezable features, see the Freezable Objects Overview.

Regarding the first example I'm not sure if the problem is that you're instantiating a SolidColorBrush object instead of binding directly to your resource.

Comment: Ok sounds like an answer to this part of the problem. I make it staticResource to a resource in Windows.Resources.  In Windows.Resources I then refer to my Application Resources.  I just dont know how to make a Color resource refer to a color resource.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this example works:

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle x:Name="dbBarPeekOutRect1" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="3,10,10,10" >
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource MyColor}" />
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>

    <Rectangle x:Name="dbBarPeekOutRect2" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Fill="{DynamicResource MyColor2}"/>

    <Button Name="ChangeResource" Content="ChangeResource" Width="100" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="ChangeResource_Click" />
</Grid>
```

Handler of `ChangeResource Button`:

```
    private void ChangeResource_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Color MyCodeColor = Colors.BlanchedAlmond;
        SolidColorBrush MyBrush = Brushes.Aquamarine;

        // Set the new value
        Application.Current.Resources["MyColor"] = MyCodeColor;
        Application.Current.Resources["MyColor2"] = MyBrush;
    }
```

I put the color in the resources `App.xaml` file:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Color x:Key="MyColor">#D8C13E</Color>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyColor2" Color="Green" />
</Application.Resources>
```

As for the animation... If I'm not mistaken, when the animation is used, an WPF Animation will lock the target properties value as long as the animation is still active. Therefore `DynamicResource` transformed into `StaticResource`. As example: also when you use the property `Opacity` in animation, the code does not have access.

Comment: Looks good.  But why does yours work. It cannot have anything to do with context right? Also my app starts fine, it is just if it is dynamically changed.

Comment: Maybe because of `SolidColorBrush` Color = `Color type`,  and to Rectangle.Fill properties need a `SolidColorBrush type`. And you use the `ColFancyMed` for all values.

Comment: To test and write the question I chagned these around. In my question I have noted that one is a color and one is a brush. It won't even compile otherwise.